# Show how multiplication between two polynomials is o(nlogm)?

Tags: algorithm

Given the following:
Two polynomials , one of degree `m` and the other of degree `n` , and I need show how 
the multiplication between them is `o(n*log(m))`, when `m<n` .

Let's say , `A(x)` has degree `n` , and `B(x)` has degree `m`.

My felling is the following :

1. We take the first polynomial , let's call it `A(x)` , and separate it to `m` parts , meaning `m/n` polynomials in the total . This would take `o(n)`.
2. Take each one of the broken polynomials and multiply it with `B(x)` using `FFT` .
3. We store the result in an array of `n+m` values .

but from here I don't know how to continue . I'd appreciate your help ,

Comment: Fix your question, you use `o` instead of `O`, also if `m < n` then is `m/n == 0` split polynomials, wth?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) for polynomial multiplication using matrices.